# matlab inverse function is not defined

Tags: matlab

I have the following code in matlab, but I get the strange error in using inverse function:

```
x = load('E:\myFile1.dat');
y = load('E:\myFile2.dat');    
ones = ones(100,1);
X = [x,ones];
XtX = X'*X;
XtXinv = inverse(XtX);
XtY = x' * y;
w = XtXinv * XtY;


??? Undefined function or method 'inverse' for input arguments of
    type 'double'.
```

I have created the script in the main (default) matlab folder in "my documents" on windows. Some people said that its because a bad current directory. But my script file is just in the "my documents". Any help on this?

Comment: `inverse` is not a Matlab function.

Comment: But [`inv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html) is, if you're attempting to calculate a matrix inverse. Though you might try `w = XtX \ XtY;`, using [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html), instead. Also, redefining the `ones` function as a variable is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Just another comment.  Calculating the inverse on its own is usually a bad idea due to numerical instability.  You should definitely use `mldivide` that @horchler is talking about.  John Cook gives a great argument as to why you should avoid finding the inverse.  Read here: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/

Comment: thanks both horchler and rayryeng for their good explanations which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no MATLAB function `inverse`. You almost certainly want to use the function `inv` instead.

However, as others have mentioned, it's usually not a good idea for reasons of numerical stability to use `inv` directly - better to use `\` or `/` to compute the final answer.